# Azure BlockBlobClient downloadWithResponse file size issue

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am running into an issue where the file size that is downloaded is bigger than what is stored on the azure blob. I am using java api. This is a problem because the checksum now no longer matches when the download is finished?

I am using the BlockBlobClient downloadWithResponse method. I am specifying a range to download using BlobRange. Do I need to be specific with the final range?

for example:
I am downloading a 101mb file. I choose a Range of of 10mb. Will my total that is downloaded be 110mb?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Will my total that is downloaded be 110mb?

The range means a range of bytes on a blob, if it's smaller than blob size then the file will be incomplete and if bigger it will only download the blob size file.

So you don't have to specify the range, you could use the blob property `BlobSize`, `Long.MAX_VALUE` or `null` they all could download the complete blob.

And in my test my files are all complete so please provide your code to let me have a test and below is my test with `null` rage. Passing null as a BlobRange value will default to the entire range of the blob.

```
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");

        String fileName ="blob.jpg";
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);

        //long dataSize = blobClient.getProperties().getBlobSize();
        //BlobRange range = new BlobRange(0, dataSize);

        OutputStream  outputStream = new FileOutputStream("E:\\"+fileName);

        DownloadRetryOptions options = new DownloadRetryOptions().setMaxRetryRequests(5);
        blobClient.downloadWithResponse(outputStream,null,options,null,false,null,null);
```